# "If", "and" excel statement

Tags: excel

I need to create and If/and statement in excel where if A1 **contains** a certain word (eg "CD*), and B1>C1, then a value of 1 is to be returned.

The catch is that I need the same criteria applied to D1 and E1>F1 and then the two values added together.

Hence if all these criteria pan out my final value returned is to be 2.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Add some examples and expected output ;).

Answer (score 1):

The logical operations are represented by formulae:

```
 AND( condition1 , condition2 , ... )

 OR( condition1 , condition2 , ... )

 NOT( condition )
```

Each condition can be pretty much anything with a logical evaluation, meaning you can nest logical operations by nesting the formulae as required.

So in your case you need:

```
 =IF( AND( A1='CD', B1>C1 ), "OK", "Not OK")
```